# How long does it take for the simple sugars in a drink to reach the bloodstream?

Tags: nutrition, sugar

We are talking about 24g of sugar in Kool Aid Jammers. Does the sugar enter the stream nearly instantaneously or does it take a while? 10 minutes? 30?

Comment: So, presumably, this is on an empty stomach? You need to specify: the amount of the beverage and sugar content in %.

Answer (score 1):

When ingesting sugar water, the body attempts to regulate movement of food from the stomach into the duodenum (first part of small intestine) to a rate of about [2.1 kcal per minute](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9838860).

Your drink that contains 24 grams of sugar will provide 96 kcal, and will likely be absorbed over a period of about 45 minutes.

A normal healthy person will have around 80-110 mg/dl of glucose circulating in their blood plasma. An average person has about 50 dl of blood circulating in their veins, or about 5 grams of glucose total. If all 24 grams of sugar entered the blood stream instantly, that would cause the blood sugar level to rise by around 480 mg/dL, which would be well above the level defined as acute hyperglycemia and high enough to put a person into the emergency room or even cause death.